# Cypher neo4j cube root

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to calculate the **cubic mean** from some nodes in neo4j.

### schema

```
create 
(n {value:1}),
(n1 {value:2}),
(n2 {value:3}),
(n3 {value:4})
```

### query

```
match (n) 
where n.value is not null 
with 
SUM(n.value^3)/COUNT(n) as this 
with
this^(1/3) as final
return final
```

### result

value=1.0

Anybody knows why?
Thank you for your time

---

EDIT1:
With this works:

```
match (n) 
where n.value is not null 
with 
SUM(n.value^3)/COUNT(n) as this 
with
this^(0.3333333) as final
return final
```

but I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Divisions with integers in Cypher result in an integer as well. You can use either `0.33333` or making it a double by using `1.0 / 3.0` to overcome that.

Comment: Works nice! Thanks! :D